# Finding pH using the -log, why does my calculation differ from the book's answer?

Tags: acid-base, solutions, ph, stoichiometry

An aqueous solution containing 0.0020 mol/L barium hydroxide, what is the pH? I do the following: 14-(-log(0.0020))=11.3pH. The answer is 11.6.

2.0*10^-3 mol/L sodium hydroxide solution, what is the pH? I do the following:
14-(-log(0.002))=11.3pH. The answer is 9.3

When I solve for pH of solutions with acidic solutes, I get the accurate answer, such as in the question: 2.0*10^3 mol/L nitric acid solution, where I do:
-log(0.002)=2.7pH, which matches the answer, 2.7.

My question is, why am I getting the discrepancy between the calculated and the given answer when calculating pH for solutions with base solute? Or am I not doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because barium hydroxide is $\ce{Ba(OH)2}$

The book is assuming each mole of barium hydroxide release 2 moles of hydroxide ions, while you are assuming only 1 mole is released.

Comment: Please disambiguate.

Comment: @ArthurAlexKarapetov OK, I added to the answer.

Comment: I see. But what about sodium hydroxide (NaOH)? There is only 1 hydroxide ion released there. In my question, it doesn't work out either. Please help understand why?

Comment: Your answer is right for 0.002M NaOH